# Push items to a constant.js into reactnative and pull from a different file

Tags: react-native

I making an app where it has a history page that contains search phrases used in the app. In my Home.js I have a user enter in a search phrase, I want that search phrase stored into a different file, and I want to be able to remove/add to it. Let's call the array file HistoryArray.js, this file **only** contains the search phrases. From there, I would like to go on my History.js screen and display each search phrase by importing the HistoryArray.js. There are multiple screens that will be pushing to HistoryArray.js and History.js will be clearing/removing search phrases.